# Changed class to derive from UITableViewController and now app won't run

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, storyboard

I have an app (Xcode 4 using Storyboard) where I created a class for a UITableView derived from **UIViewController**.  It sorta worked until I figured out that I had created the class in error... it should have derived from UITableViewController.

So I created the replacement class as it should have been (UITableViewController), and changed the class of the view in Storyboard to match the name of the newly created UITableViewClass.  It builds just fine, but when I go to run it, it crashes with the error:

> [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the
>   "BaL-ay-iTG-view-otY-DM-YDS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Since this is using Storyboard, I don't have access to the NIB.  Is there any way I can fix this besides re-writing the entire app?  (I have tried "clean" several times, to no avail)

Comment: Do you have a table view in the Interface Builder? I think that the view controller that calls this class has no table view.

Comment: Yes, I have a table view in IB...

Comment: check the connection of your tableview in interfacebuilder. that should solve your problem.

Comment: what connection?  do you mean making sure the "class name" matches the UITableViewController name?  If so, I double-checked it... it seems that something didn't get cleaned up or something...

Comment: Check the “-view” outlet of your UITableViewController in the interface builder. Does it point to a UITableView? Does it point to a UIView? Does it point to nothing? (hint: it should point to a UITableView; anything else causes that exception to be thrown).

Comment: Yep... that's the problem...is there a way I can change it other than re-creating the view and dragging the objects to the new view?  (Please respond as an Answer and not a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to David Cairns for the answer.  I appreciate it! I quote from above:

> Check the “-view” outlet of your UITableViewController in the
>   interface builder. Does it point to a UITableView? Does it point to a
>   UIView? Does it point to nothing? (hint: it should point to a
>   UITableView; anything else causes that exception to be thrown). –
>   David Cairns